# Animated UIButton not registering press

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I am trying to make a slide out notification bar for when the app receives a notification and the app is currently open and in the foreground. I got this working with a custom `UIView` (actually it's a `UIButton`) and an animation. For some reason though it won't register a press when I tap on it. It won't call the selector method. Code is below:

```
-(void)appOpenPush {

   //get string
    NSLog(@"got a push while app was open");
    AppDelegate *appDelegate =(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSString *pushString = appDelegate.pushString;

    //play sound
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(MessageSound);
    AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);


    //note I am actually using a button here
    UIButton *pushView =[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -75, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width,75)];
    pushView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.8];
    [pushView addTarget:self action:@selector(pushSlidePress) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    //set image
    UIImageView *logo = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon120.png"]];
    logo.frame=CGRectMake(5, 20, 35, 35);
    logo.layer.cornerRadius=8;
    logo.clipsToBounds=YES;
    [pushView addSubview:logo];

    UILabel *pushLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(48, 34, 0, 0)];
    pushLabel.text=pushString;
    pushLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
    [pushLabel sizeToFit];
    pushLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    [pushView addSubview:pushLabel];


    //animate
    UIWindow* currentWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    [currentWindow addSubview:pushView];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        pushView.frame  = CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width,75);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 delay:2.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
            pushView.frame  = CGRectMake(0, -75, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width,75);

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [pushView removeFromSuperview];
        }];

    }];

}
```

Could anyone give me a pointer to why this isn't working? Is it because I am adding the `UIButton` to the main window? Any tips would be really helpful. thanks!

Comment: So you only want to be able to tap on the view while it is being animated ? since you remove it from the superview when the animation finishes ? is that right

Comment: That's right yeah. It's a hidden view that slides out when a notification is received.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` as an option to both of your animation blocks.

As per the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIViewAnimationOptions) :

"Allow the user to interact with views while they are being animated."

Comment: How do I use multiple options in it?

Comment: @Kex Use "bitwise or" - `|`.

Comment: won't that only use one of the options?

Comment: No its bitwise OR - `options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn| UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction`

Answer (score 0):

Try this to avoid logo and pushLabel receive touches events:

```
logo.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
pushLabel.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out you can't simply detect a press if the button is moving. I tested this by just adding the frame setup without it animating and it registered the press, when animation is turned on it doesn't. Seems that `UIButton` doesn't have tracking built in. I did come up with a quick fix. I just made a button the same size as the total animation area (i.e. the size of my slide out bar) and added that to the currentWindow on top of the animation frame. So it's just a clear invisible button on top of the animation but it's not moving itself. i.e:

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width , 75)];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(pushSlidePress) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[currentWindow addSubview:button];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 delay:0.0 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction) animations:^{
    pushView.frame  = CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width,75);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 delay:2.0 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction) animations:^{
        pushView.frame  = CGRectMake(0, -75, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width,75);

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [pushView removeFromSuperview];
        [button removeFromSuperview];
    }];

}];
```

Obviously you are covering an area of the screen that might block other things being pressed, but it depends on your setup. The animation is quick and I only have one button that the notification bar will block and it's too quick to notice. Hopefully this will be helpful to someone else trying to achieve a similar thing. Thanks for your help guys.